# Phonegap Build Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I've tried creating the certificate and provisioning profile over and over again, but I cannot get it to build on iOS through Phonegap Build. I get this error every time:

> Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching

I've done this many times in the past, but for whatever reason I can't get it to work now.

The provisioning profile contains the certificate and I can generate the .p12 file just fine.

My mac will only allow me to upgrade OS up to 10.13.6 and xcode up to 10.1. Is there any issue with keychain using older versions of these?

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

After updating OS and xcode I scrubbed keychain, created new certificate signing requests, revoked all the old certificates in apple developer and then created a new certificate and profile.